# Pipeline with resource pipeline trigger to post status to pull request

Tags: azure-pipelines

I would like to create a workflow like this:

```
topic/feature branch -> PR to pre-prod branch

                     -> Build validation trigger build pipeline (branch policy)

                     -> After Build pipeline runs, run a validation pipeline that consumes artifacts from the build pipeline. The validation pipeline should post it's status to the PR.
```

This is somewhat possible to accomplish.

The build runs, and the validation pipelines runs by setting up a trigger by using resource pipeline trigger.

But the problem is that the status from the validation pipeline isn't posted to the Pull Request. So I loose visibility into if the PR should actually be merged or not.

Is there a way to also get the validation pipeline to post it's status to the PR?

E.g. like this:
[image: pipeline run]

The same question was asked two years ago here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62710338/3904492

It does seem like the feature is not yet possible.

From the documentation this is what I want to accomplish, but how can Pipeline B report it's status to the PR?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your requirement, you need to show the validation pipeline status in Pull Request.

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can meet your requirement for the time being.

Currently, Pull requests can only display Build Pipelines status connected through the branch policy's build validation. In your case, it shows name as build pipeline.

It does not support displaying the status of pipeline B triggered by the build  pipeline.

For a workaround, you can show the validation pipeline status in Pull Request Comment.

You can use PowerShell task in Pipeline to run  the Rest API: [Timeline - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to monitor the pipeline status and then you can use the Rest API: [Pull Request Thread Comments - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-thread-comments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP) to show the Pipeline status to Pull Request comment.

Here is PowerShell example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/timeline?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))



$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

$errors = $response.records.Where({ $_.result -eq "failed" })

$count = 0

$errors.ForEach({
   
   $_.name

   $_.issues.ForEach({ $_.message })
   $count = $count + 1
})

If($count -gt 0)
{

$JSON = @'
"{
  `"content`": `"Pipeline Test is failed. `",
  `"parentCommentId`": 1,
  `"commentType`": 1

}"
   
'@

}

else
{
$JSON = @'
"{
  `"content`": `"Pipeline Test is succeed. `",
  `"parentCommentId`": 1,
  `"commentType`": 1

}"
   
'@
}

$url1="https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/git/repositories/repoID/pullRequests/22/threads/148/comments?api-version=5.1"

$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Method POST -Body $JSON -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

On the other hand, I can fully understand your requirement. I suggest that you can create a suggestion feedback in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report the feature request.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is the way to go. I created script to get a reference to the PR. I'll update sometime later for anyone else curious.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could edit your build validation yaml as below, and I task dotnet build for example.

```
  steps: 
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: BuildValidation
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: 'xxx'
      continueOnError: true  ##This is necessary.

    - script: echo "Validation Start"    

###You could define your condition custom with below, 
###and I took check the pipeline status for example.
    - ${{ if eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded') }}:  
      - script: echo "The Validation Succeeded"

    - ${{ else }}:
      - script: |
              echo "The Validation Failed"
              exit 1
```

[image]